# Kotlin Java DSL: Transforming from byte[] to String

Tags: spring-integration

I am working on converting the `tcp-client-server` example of Spring Integration to using Java DSL and Kotlin.

In my inbound TCP server I need to convert a `byte[]` coming from the channel into a `String` for my echo service.

This is my current flow definition:

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
class ClientServerDemoConfig {

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "input", name = "gw")
interface SimpleGateway {
    fun send(text: String): String
}

@Bean
fun outboundTCP() =
    IntegrationFlows.from("input")
        .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1", 7777)))
        .get()

@Bean
fun inboundTCP() =
    IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundGateway(TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(7777)))
        .transform<Array<Byte>, String> { p -> String(p.toByteArray()) }
        .handle(EchoService(), "test")
        .get()
```

Which when run in intellij results in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'byte[]' to required type 'java.lang.String': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
```

Weird thing is when debugging I can see the transformer being executed, but then I get lost in the details trying to find out why it is not behaving.

Can someone please give some input on what I'm not doing or doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
    compile('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ip')
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2018-07-10 16:53:59.726 ERROR 20187 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at alwyn.tcpclientserver.ClientServerDemoApplicationKt.main(ClientServerDemoApplication.kt:29) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'byte[]' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'byte[]' to required type 'java.lang.String': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:44) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.convert(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:763) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:532) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:469) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:460) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.send(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at alwyn.tcpclientserver.ClientServerDemoApplication.run(ClientServerDemoApplication.kt:19) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'byte[]' to required type 'java.lang.String': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:73) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think that `IllegalStateException` comes from other place, not your `.transform()`. Please, share with us a full stack trace for better context to get the whole picture.

Comment: When I run with spring boot debugging enabled it checks the conditions and for some reason complains about FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@3b8f5ed failed, but I don't have any mention of spring data or jdbc or anything sql related in my build.gradle.

Comment: Well. that's absolutely not related to that `.transform()`. Please, don't mix concerns in a single SO question. Let's concentrate on the reported problem!

Comment: ok I'll add full stacktrace for transform and my dependencies.

Comment: ??? No, I'm talking about an `Exception stack trace`: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Stack_trace. I don't need your dependencies. You just need to show more from the logs around that `IllegalStateException`

Comment: Looks like the gateway proxy is trying to do some conversion too?

Comment: Do you have a bytesToString transformer back on the client side (like the `clientBytes2String` in the XML config)? In both places (after the inbound tranformer, after the outbound gateway) you should be able to use `.transform(Transformers.objectToString())`.

Comment: Right and that's fully not related to that `.transform()` as I told before. There is some in the `alwyn.tcpclientserver.ClientServerDemoApplication.run(ClientServerDemoApplication.kt:19)` you don show to us. And right: it looks like you call from there some gateway which expects a `String` as a return type, but the integration flow you call from there produces a `byte[]` as a reply message payload. And that's already not a `Tcp.inboundGateway()`, although it can be a `Tcp.outboundGateway()` though...

Comment: Updating with full config.  Gary, no I have no transforming on client side yet.

Comment: In both places (after the inbound tranformer, after the outbound gateway) you should be able to use `.transform(Transformers.objectToString())`.

Comment: Show your client side, please. The part you call from that gateway.

Comment: It is almost as if the gateway is trying to do a conversion before it gets to the transformer.

Comment: No, you problem is on the client side, not a server. See my answer.

Comment: I'll try it quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCP/IP is really a `byte[]` protocol, so that is fully natural that this type is expected to be send to outbound side and received from the inbound side.

For your `fun send(text: String): String` gateway contract you really need to add a `byte[] -> String` conversion/transformation after receiving reply via `Tcp.outboundGateway()`. Therefore to fix the situation for your, you need have something like this on the client side:

```
@Bean
fun outboundTCP() =
    IntegrationFlows.from("input")
        .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1", 7777)))
        .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
        .get()
```